# cannot send mail using mailgun

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, mailgun

I am using mailgun driver in laravel app and tried to send mail. But it gives me this error

```
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required
```

config/mail.php

```
'driver' => env('mailgun', 'smtp'),
'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'arshaikh_17@hotmail.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],
```

.env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

services.php

```
'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('mydomain.com.pk'),
        'secret' => env('key-********************'),
    ],
```

What is wrong with my settings and is there anything else you need to check? Please help I have been trying to study laracast for past 2 days but it doesn't send mail.

Answer (score 1):

Your config is all messed up. This part in `mail.php`:

```
'driver' => env('mailgun', 'smtp'),
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'arshaikh_17@hotmail.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],
```

Should've stayed the way it initially was.
Then you change the configuration in the `.env` file in the project root. So if you have in your `mail.php`the following line:

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
```

Then in your `.env` file you can change the value of the property `MAIL_DRIVER` to `mailgun`.

In laravel 5.4 the mail part of my `.env` file looks something like this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@somelongstring.mailgun.org
MAIL_PASSWORD=verysecretstring
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=somelongstring.mailgun.org
MAILGUN_SECRET=key-somelongstring
```

And I have not changed anything in the files in the `config` directory. The values for all of these variables you can find under your domain if you login to mailgun.

Also, read the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail or try to find a tutorial about setting up mailgun with laravel.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at how to use environment configurations as described in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration#environment-configuration):

When using the `env()` function, the first argument should be the name of the variable as defined in your `.env` file, while the second argument is the default.

Thus, in your `config/mail.php` and `services.php` you should be referring to variables which you have defined in your `env()` file as follows:

config/mail.php

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME'),
],
```

services.php

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
    'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
],
```

.env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=arshaikh_17@hotmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=Example
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=mydomain.com.pk
MAILGUN_SECRET=key-********************
```

Note that I often do not specify default values for, for example, your `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS` since this will mostly vary from installation to installation. Further, you should never store API secrets like `MAILGUN_SECRET` in files like services.php which are often version controlled.

Answer (score 0):

use their lib

install：

```
php composer.phar require mailgun/mailgun-php php-http/guzzle6-adapter php-http/message
```

include：

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Mailgun\Mailgun;
```

new object：

```
$mgClient = new Mailgun('YOUR_API_KEY');
```

See Example
https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-sending.html#examples

Answer (score 0):

To me it was that I was using an incorrect value for MAILGUN_SECRET env variable, at first I was using a key that I received through email but the required value was the api secret key that is way longer. Api secret key can be found in: Settings -> API Keys -> Private API key at mailgun.org